# How to prove a formula for the midpoint of a line between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vectors, theorem-provers

how to prove that OP1 + 0,5 * P1P2 = OC?

C is the midpoint of P1P2.

Thank you

[Click here for the image that illustrates the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6a2M.png)

Answer (score 0):

Show that $OC-OP_1=OP_2-OC$, which is perhaps the definition of midpoint.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, being $C$ is the mid point of $\vec{P_1P_2}$, you have: 
$$\vec{P_1C}=\vec{CP_1}$$
Now, by the definition of the sum between vectors, follows that:
$$\vec{OP_1}+\vec{CP_1}=\vec{OC}$$